# How can I manipulate JSON data without side effects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, functional-programming

Consider the following code

```
var myData = {name: 'John'};

function fixName(data) {
    var newData = data;
    newData.name = 'Mike';
    return newData;
}

var myData2 = fixName(myData);
console.log(myData2.name);
console.log(myData.name);
```

'Mike' is printed twice because within my function, newData and myData point to the same thing.  How can I alter my function so that it has no side effects upon myData?  This means the program should print 'Mike' then 'John'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone that data object.

What is the best way to clone an object is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

```
// jQuery
newData = $.extend({}, data);
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/575527) for an explanation about "cloning" an object (which is really complex), or take the easy route and use [jQuery extend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/575527) provided by J.Resig himself which technically abstracts this cloning code into a simple syntax

Answer (score 2):

So basically you want to create a copy of an object instead of getting a reference?

If this is the case, you may be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) where the accepted answer uses a simple piece of jQuery to do it.

If, like me, you don't want to use jQuery, you can just use a loop to get a basic copy:

```
var myData2 = {};
for( var x in myData) if( myData.hasOwnProperty(x)) myData2[x] = myData[x];
// Copied!
```

This is actually enough for any object that is just being used as an associative array (as yours appears to be, and as most JSON objects are).

Answer (score 1):

To clone `myData`, you could use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myData))`:

```
var myData = {name: 'John'};

function fixName(data) {
    var newData = data;
    newData.name = 'Mike';
    return newData;
}

var myData2 = fixName( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myData)) );
console.log(myData2.name); //=> Mike
console.log(myData.name);  //=> John
```

This will clone nested objects too, by the way.

It may be an idea to make a function out of it:

```
function cloneObj(obj,reviver){
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj),reviver);
}
```

Where `reviver` could be used to manipulate data in the object, in your case that would make `fixName` obsolete.

```
var myData2 = cloneObj(myData, function(k,v){return k === 'name' ? 'Mike' : v;});
```